# Inserting a cell in Word table, that shifts the last cell onto the next row ... Can it be done?

Tags: microsoft-word, cells, word-wrap

I have a Word document in which I have a succession of cells, arranged in alphabetical order reading across. It is six cells wide by however long it goes down.

What I want to be able to do, is add another item midway through, which will push everything in that row to the right, and then knock the last one on that row to the start of the next.

So, for example:

> Aberdeen -tab- Ashford -tab- Bath -tab- Bedford -tab- Birmingham -tab- Bolton
>
> Bradford -tab- Carlisle -tab- Cheltenham -tab- Chester -tab- Corby -tab- Derby
>
> etc

Now, I might want to add a new entry to this list, let's say Blackpool. So I want to add it after Birmingham, then shift Bolton onto the next line, which will then push Derby onto the line after that, and so on.

Is this possible?

I can get somewhere close by doing it reading downwards, in ordinary text and then using Columns rather than a table. But not horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic way to do this that is built into Word. Word table cells are fixed to their position in the table row. You cannot drag the cell and its content someplace else.

To accomplish what you want requires a macro. The following macro should work for you based on what you have told us. It requires that your current selection point is in the table cell content that you want to shift to the right.

```
Sub ShiftRightAndDown()
    Dim tbl As Word.Table, rng As Word.Range
    Dim LastCellNbr As Long, SaveCellNbr As Long
    
    If Not Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
        MsgBox "Selection is not withing a table cell", vbExclamation, "Shift Cell Content Right"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set tbl = Selection.Tables(1)
    LastCellNbr = tbl.Range.Cells.Count
    Set rng = Selection.Cells(1).Range
    For i = 1 To LastCellNbr
        If rng.InRange(tbl.Range.Cells(i).Range) Then
            SaveCellNbr = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    If Len(tbl.Range.Cells(LastCellNbr).Range.Text) > 2 Then
        tbl.Range.rows.Add
        LastCellNbr = tbl.Range.Cells.Count
    End If
    
    If SaveCellNbr = LastCellNbr Then
        tbl.Range.rows.Add
        LastCellNbr = tbl.Range.Cells.Count
    End If
    
    For i = LastCellNbr To SaveCellNbr Step -1
        Set rng = tbl.Range.Cells(i).Range
        rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
        If Len(rng.Text) > 0 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    For i = i To SaveCellNbr Step -1
        tbl.Range.Cells(i + 1).Range.FormattedText = rng.FormattedText
        Set rng = tbl.Range.Cells(i - 1).Range
        rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
    Next
    
    Set rng = tbl.Range.Cells(SaveCellNbr).Range
    rng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
    rng.Text = ""
    
errHandler:
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Shift Cell Content Right"
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve that by using textboxes, with its properties for position set to be inline with text (and sized so that you fit 6 in a line across page).  You could then copy and paste an existing textbox in the spot you want to insert it and edit with your new entry text.